# PropTypes of specific component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this simple React component:

```
import {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Column from './Column';

export default function ColumnContainer({children}) {
    return (
        <div className="cr-column-container">{children}</div>
    );
}

let ColumnType = PropTypes.instanceOf(Column);

ColumnContainer.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        ColumnType,
        PropTypes.arrayOf(ColumnType),
    ]).isRequired,
};
```

Which I use like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <ColumnContainer>
            <Column>
                *snip*
            </Column>
        </ColumnContainer>
    );
}
```

But it's failing prop-type validation:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ColumnContainer`.
    in ColumnContainer (created by ExampleContainer)
    in ExampleContainer
```

Why is that? I've only used `Column`s inside of the `ColumnContainer`. Does `PropTypes.instanceOf(Column)` not work like I expect? How am I *supposed* to specify that `ColumnContainer` will only accept children of type `Column`?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2979

Comment: @jamesemanon Just found that. None of the solutions presented are ideal though.

Answer (score 4):

Did some digging, came up with this helper function based on [josephmartin09's solution](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2979#issuecomment-222379916):

```
export function childrenOf(...types) {
    let fieldType = PropTypes.shape({
        type: PropTypes.oneOf(types),
    });

    return PropTypes.oneOfType([
        fieldType,
        PropTypes.arrayOf(fieldType),
    ]);
}
```

Usage:

```
ColumnContainer.propTypes = {
    children: childrenOf(Column).isRequired,
};
```

It's not ideal because it doesn't support native DOM elements like `'div'` and the error message is worthless, but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I overhauled `childrenOf` with support for react-hot-loader 4.x:

```
import { areComponentsEqual } from 'react-hot-loader';

export function childrenOf(...types) {
    return requirable((props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) => {
        const component = props[propName];
        if(!location) {
            location = 'prop';
        }
        if(!propFullName) {
            propFullName = propName;
        }
        const check = c => types.some(type => areComponentsEqual(type,c.type));
        const valid = Array.isArray(component) ? component.every(check) : check(component);
        if(!valid) {
            return new Error(
                `Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`. Every element must be a <${types.map(t => getDisplayName(t)).join('|')}>.`
            );
        }
        return null;
    });
}

function requirable(predicate) {
    const propType = (props, propName, ...rest) => {
        // don't do any validation if empty
        if(props[propName] === undefined) {
            return null;
        }

        return predicate(props, propName, ...rest);
    };

    propType.isRequired = (props, propName, componentName, ...rest) => {
        // warn if empty
        if(props[propName] === undefined) {
            return new Error(`Required prop \`${propName}\` was not specified in \`${componentName}\`.`);
        }

        return predicate(props, propName, componentName, ...rest);
    };

    return propType;
}
```

Usage example:

```
export function TBody({children, ...attrs}) {
    return <tbody {...attrs}>{children}</tbody>;
}

TBody.propTypes = {
    children: WxTypes.childrenOf(TRow),
};
```