# Describing children as instanceOf or array of instanceOf's with prop-types

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to enforce a specific type of children in my component.

```
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.instanceOf(Column),
  PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Column))
])
```

Usage

```
<Table data={data}>
  <Column field='foo' />
  <Column field='bar' />
</Table>

<Table data={data}>
  <Column field='baz' />
</Table>
```

I still get a warning with both of the above.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to
>   `Table`.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: is Column a class component?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk edited my answer with the warning(not error). It is a react component. `class Column extends Component`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456901/proptypes-of-specific-component

Comment: @YuryTarabanko didn't work for me

Comment: React component should be a `PropTypes.node`. If you are sure there should always be `Column`, it would be better to pass column props instead of the whole component.

Comment: @Sulthan i don't understand what you're suggesting. Do you mind posting an example?